# RegEx: Find domains and subdomains based on a whitelist

Tags: regex

I have this list:

```
something.microsoft.com
something.bing.de
somethingmicrosoft.com
something-bing.com
microsoft.com
bing.de
```

My goal is to filter the domains that have subdomains or nothing at all.
So in the end it should look like this:

```
something.microsoft.com
something.bing.de
microsoft.com
bing.de
```

There should be a whitelist in the regular expression, so only selected substrings are allowed for the SLD and TLD (separated).

This is what I tried so far:

```
(?:.*)\.{0,1}(?:microsoft|bing)(?:\.de|\.com)
(?:.*\.){0,1}(?:microsoft|bing)(?:\.de|\.com)
```

As you can see it also finds somethingmicrosoft.com. How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: You added a `(?:.*\.){0,1}(?:microsoft|bing)(?:\.de|\.com)` pattern to the question at the moment I posted my answer, and it is almost correct, it is just missing anchors. `{0,1}` quantifier works the same as the `?` quantifier. Repeating `\.` in the last alternation is redundant if you move `\.` before the parentheses.

Comment: Anchors do not "mark", but "require" the start/end positions. And not regex match start/end, but *the input string* start and end positions.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I think I now completely understand the anchor thing. Before, I just thought I understood it.

Comment: Hello again! I could need help again. I got a case where I don't want to match it whenever there's a slash before the domain. In this example I don't want to match the last entry: https://regex101.com/r/pGia8c/1
How can I achieve this? I've tried it with an anchor and negative lookahead but it didn't work. I think I did it wrong when I matched everything with .* and wanted to exclude the slash (I've escaped it properly). Any ideas?

Comment: You may use `^(?:[^\/]*\.)?(?:google|bing)\.(?:de|com|net)$`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pGia8c/2) (the `\n` is used in the negated character class since this is a multiline string demo, when used against standalone strings, it will work as expected without `\n`)

Comment: You're a beast, thank you so much again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```r
^(?:.*\.)?(?:microsoft|bing)\.(?:de|com)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FyKTb7/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:.*\.)?` - an optional sequence of any chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, followed with a literal `.` char
- `(?:microsoft|bing)` - `microsoft` or `bing`
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?:de|com)` - `de` or `com`
- `$` - end of string.